# Does reproducing a board game as a video game violate copyright?

Tags: copyright

The context I am thinking of is converting a board game into a video game or app. Of course, I can't manufacture a physical copy of the game without permission, but does the same apply to a virtual version? My understanding is that copyright protects only the particular manner of an author’s expression. This means that the board game is copyrighted, but a video game with the same mechanics is not. Is that the case?

Answer (score 3):

Game mechanics are not copyright able. However, the images, words used, description of the rules are all copyright. If the original games is the *source* of the video game then the video game is a derivative work. If the original game is only the *inspiration* and the *look and feel* is different then this is OK. Which is which will turn on the actual facts.

Comment: So, if the video game implements all of the rules identically to the board game, but uses entirely original images and description of the rules, then it does not count as a derivative work?

Comment: If the layout of the board is not purely functional, it may also be copyrightable.